# Question on circular motion and its application on a beam

Tags: kinematics, free-body-diagram

The question is an IB diploma physics HL question shown here, it is on circular motion: !https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/263571466208018433/445134832574529546/Screen_Shot_2018-05-13_at_4.03.55_PM.png

In this question, I was wondering further that how shall I draw a free body diagram for when the mass is at π/2 angle to its original position at the top, i.e. at the rightmost or leftmost.

In the case of the ball at the leftmost undergoing circular motion where acceleration is to the center: Since Force of weight is downwards, and circular motion is present such that Fnet is to the center, does that mean the force of the beam in that time is to the center and upwards to both balance the weight and also create an rightward force? But the force of the beam on the mass seems to be tension, so it shouldn't create a upward force and instead acts along the string only to the right. There seems to be a contradiction. How should a correct free body diagram be drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information that the mass is rotating in a circle of **constant** radius, $r$, at a **constant** speed, $v$, you can infer that the sum of the two forces acting on the mass,

- its weight $mg$ (which is assumed to be **constant**), and
- the force due to the rod $F_{\rm rod}$

must add together to give a **constant** net force which provides the **constant** centripetal acceleration, $\dfrac{v^2}{r}$, of the mass.

The diagram below shows the summation of these two forces at two positions in the motion with the magnitudes (lengths of vectors) $mg$ and $\dfrac{mv^2}{r}$ constant.

[image]

Comment: So the force of the rod is not tension force? Hence why it can be in that direction when the rod itself is towards the center. If so, what happens if the rod is swapped to a rope?

Comment: @LHC2012 The answer I have given would not apply to a rope as a rope can only sustain a tension force. The rod can push as well as pull the mass and not necessarily towards or away from the centre of rotation.

Comment: So what would happen if the rod is replaced by the rope? how would the free body diagram then be drawn at that instant in time? (assuming it also has uniform circular motion)

Comment: Two forces again, the weight always vertical downwards and the force (tension) due to the rope always towards the centre.

Comment: Though this seems to lead to the net force in the end going upwards as well if I add up weight and tension. Does that mean in that case there is no uniform circular motion?

Comment: @LHC2012 Yes the mass cannot move at constant speed if a rope is used.

Answer (score 0):

No, at the left and rightmost points the centripedal force and force of gravity are perpendicular to eachother; the mass's weight does not contribute to the force in the rod. I think you're getting confused because you're wondering how the speed of rotation can be constant when the force of gravity is means that the mass will accelerate towards the ground and deaccelrate when moving upwards. This is a legitimate concern, and in reality, if this system wasn't being driven by some sort of motor, we would expect the mass to reach almost an exact stop at the top of the circle and have a maximum speed at the bottom. However, remember that these exams questions are idealised: the examiner isn't looking for you to talk about some changing angular velocity and is instead trying to assess your knowledge on force diagrams and centrifugal force, which is why they asserted that the angular velocity is constant.